# Suppressing Camel specific attributes from Camel generated swagger definition

Tags: apache-camel, swagger, aws-api-gateway

I am using camel-swagger to generate the API definition of my service. Please find below the generated swagger definition -

```
{
  "swagger" : "2.0",
  "info" : {
    "description" : "api.description",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "title" : "api.title",
    "termsOfService" : "api.termsOfService",
    "contact" : {
      "name" : "api.contact.name",
      "url" : "http://api.contact.url",
      "email" : "api@demo.com"
    },
    "license" : {
      "name" : "api.license.name",
      "url" : "http://api.license.url"
    }
  },
  "host" : "0.0.0.0:13000",
  "basePath" : "/airportinfo-service/1.0",
  "tags" : [ {
    "name" : "airports"
  } ],
  "schemes" : [ "http" ],
  "paths" : {
    "/airports" : {
      "get" : {
        "tags" : [ "airports" ],
        "parameters" : [ ],
        "responses" : {
          "200" : {
            "description" : "Output type",
            "schema" : {
              "$ref" : "#/definitions/Airports"
            }
          }
        },
        "x-camelContextId" : "airportinfo-service",
        "x-routeId" : "getAirports"
      }
    },
    "/airports/{id}" : {
      "get" : {
        "tags" : [ "airports" ],
        "parameters" : [ {
          "name" : "id",
          "in" : "path",
          "description" : "",
          "required" : true,
          "type" : "string"
        } ],
        "responses" : {
          "200" : {
            "description" : "Output type",
            "schema" : {
              "$ref" : "#/definitions/Airport"
            }
          }
        },
        "x-camelContextId" : "airportinfo-service",
        "x-routeId" : "getAirport"
      }
    },
    "/airports/health" : {
      "get" : {
        "tags" : [ "airports" ],
        "parameters" : [ ],
        "responses" : {
          "200" : {
            "description" : "Output type",
            "schema" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "format" : "java.lang.String"
            }
          }
        },
        "x-camelContextId" : "airportinfo-service",
        "x-routeId" : "health"
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions" : {
    "Airport" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {
          "type" : "integer",
          "format" : "int64"
        },
        "airportIataCode" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "airportName" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "airportStatus" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "airportLatitude" : {
          "type" : "number",
          "format" : "double"
        },
        "airportLongitude" : {
          "type" : "number",
          "format" : "double"
        },
        "airportUrl" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "cityId" : {
          "type" : "integer",
          "format" : "int64"
        },
        "cityIataCode" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "cityName" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "cityLatitude" : {
          "type" : "number",
          "format" : "double"
        },
        "cityLongitude" : {
          "type" : "number",
          "format" : "double"
        },
        "cityStatus" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "cityCategory" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "countryId" : {
          "type" : "integer",
          "format" : "int64"
        },
        "countryIataCode" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "countryName" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "region" : {
          "type" : "string"
        }
      },
      "x-className" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "format" : "demo.service.composite.airportinfo.datatypes.Airport"
      }
    },
    "Airports" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "properties" : {
        "size" : {
          "type" : "integer",
          "format" : "int32"
        },
        "airports" : {
          "type" : "array",
          "items" : {
            "$ref" : "#/definitions/Airport"
          }
        }
      },
      "x-className" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "format" : "demo.service.composite.airportinfo.datatypes.Airports"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code that generates the aforementioned API definition is -

```
    restConfiguration()
        .component("{{server.component}}")
            .host("{{server.host}}")
            .port("{{server.port}}")
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
            .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
            .contextPath("/{{service.name}}/{{service.version}}")
                .apiContextPath( "/" )
                    .apiProperty("api.title", "{{api.title}}")
                    .apiProperty("api.version", "{{service.version}}")
                    .apiProperty("api.description", "{{api.description}}")
                    .apiProperty("api.termsOfService", "{{api.termsOfService}}")
                    .apiProperty("api.contact.name", "{{api.contact.name}}")
                    .apiProperty("api.contact.email", "{{api.contact.email}}")
                    .apiProperty("api.contact.url", "{{api.contact.url}}")
                    .apiProperty("api.license.name", "{{api.license.name}}")
                    .apiProperty("api.license.url", "{{api.license.url}}")
                    .apiProperty("apiContextIdListing", "{{apiContextIdListing}}")
                    .apiProperty("apiContextIdPattern", "{{apiContextIdPattern}}");

    rest("/airports")
        .get()
        .id("getAirports")
            .outType(Airports.class)
            .to("direct:getAirports")
        .get("/{id}")
        .id("getAirport")
            .outType(Airport.class)
            .to("direct:getAirport")
        .get("/health")
        .id("health")
            .outType(String.class)
            .to("direct:health");
```

Now, I want to import this definition in AWS API Gateway. But, the same is not getting accepted because of the following portions in the API definition given above -

1. Need to remove

   ```
   "x-className" : {
       "type" : "string",
       "format" : "demo.service.composite.airportinfo.datatypes.Airport"
   }
   ```
2. Need to remove

   ```
   "x-className" : {
       "type" : "string",
       "format" : "demo.service.composite.airportinfo.datatypes.Airports"
   }
   ```
3. Need to replace

   ```
   "schema" : {
       "type" : "string",
       "format" : "java.lang.String"
   }
   ```

   with

   ```
   "schema" : {
       "format" : "String"
   }
   ```

Making these changes, I am able to import the definition in AWS API Gateway easily.

Is there a way to suppress Camel specific attributes in the swagger definition generated using camel-swagger?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, they are always included.

These types are extensions, eg they start with `x-` as documented in the spec: https://swagger.io/specification/#specificationExtensions

I logged a ticket to add support for this in the next release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11957

And we also fixed the primitive types in the responses to not use the format: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11960